# Rails3, Devise: login as any user without pass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I need a button that takes login for certain user without entering the password. This will be done by admin.

How can I do this? Or devise.token_authenticatable is the only normal solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `token_authenticatable`, but there are also helper methods called `sign_in` and `sign_out`. By giving `sign_in` a user object this user is being signed in.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [sign_in](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise/Controllers/SignInOut#sign_in-instance_method) or [sign_in_and_redirect](http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Controllers/Helpers:sign_in_and_redirect)

```
class AdminController < ApplicationController
  def my_action

    # Retrieve your user
    user = User.where( :id => [...] )

    # Sign in
    sign_in :user, user

    # Or...
    # sign_in_and_redirect :user, user

  end
end
```

Comment: (dead link on `sign_in`)

Answer (score 2):

You can user gem [switch_user](https://github.com/flyerhzm/switch_user)